# Issues with derivative of a copula density

Tags: descriptive-statistics, copula

Suppose I have a bivariate copula density with marginals $F(X)$ ($F(X)$ is normal with parameters $\mu_1$, $\sigma_1^2$) and $G(Y)$ ($G(Y)$ is normal with parameters $\mu_2$ and $\sigma_2^2$).
I want to take a derivative of the copula density $c(u,v;\theta)$ with respect to $\mu_1$. I would be grateful if someone can clear my following doubts about this problem.

Let $u=F(X),\,v=G(Y)$.

1) Is this the right way to calculate this derivative?

$\frac{{\rm d}c(u,v;\theta)}{{\rm d}\mu_1}=\frac{{\rm d}c(u,v;\theta)}{{\rm d}u}*\frac{{\rm d}F(X)}{{\rm d}\mu_1}$ ?

2) Here when I take the derivative of $F(X)$ w.r.t to $\mu_1$, should I assume $\sigma^2$ as given?

3) Is there any better way to approach this problem in copula estimation?

Comment: $F(X)$ being normal with $\mu$ and $\sigma$ is usually written as $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$. 1) Looks ok; 2) you differentiate with respect to $\mu_1$, so you assume $\sigma^2$ to be constant.

Comment: But the issue is in copula, F(X)=u is actually the probability integral transform which lies in [0,1]. Do we need to differentiate it wrt to mu1?